# Find all solutions of the system of equations depending on the parameters $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, matrix-equations

I have a system o linear equations dependent on parameters $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$. I am not quite sure what to do with it. My only intuition is, that if I were to use Gaussian elimination to get the pivots (from column space), I could somehow determine what are the conditions of $a$ and $b$. Is it on the right track, or can someone help me find a better way of looking at it?

$\begin{bmatrix}
  -i & a & 1+2i &\bigm| & 0 \\
  1 & 3i & b & \bigm| & 0 \\
  i & -3 & -i & \bigm| & -1
\end{bmatrix}$

Note: The word "parameter" is used here in a different sense than "free variable". By assignment it is meant that for each choice of complex numbers
$ a, b $
you are to find all solutions of a given system of three equations with three unknowns. It is possible that the existence, number of solutions, etc., depends on
$ a, b $ - let's discuss. We need to solve the system for all choices of
$ a, b $.

Comment: I suggest to compute firstly the determinant to determine what values a and b should have so the system of linear equations have a solution. I mean the determinant should be non null

Comment: the determinant would be (i*a)+(i*a*b)-(3*i*b)-(3*i)

Comment: Hint : it is equal to $(ai-3i)(1+b) $

Comment: Right, the determinant should be non-null, given the expression in bracket form, it implies that b != 1, and a != 3. Given the NULL values of a, b -> what does that mean in respect to the solution of the matrix on input?

Comment: ad the third row onto the first row. Then add $i$ times the third row onto the second row.